# CKEditor display formatted(with CKEditor CSS) HTML from database

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This is my first post so I would like to say it's nice to join this community and I will do my best to help others but I'm the one that needs help right now.

**--Problem**

I've got problem with displaying proper styling of text retrieved from `CKE` with `.getData()`, saved into DB and displayed in article.

**--When it works?**

When I include this CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="\js\ckeditor\contents.css">
```

in my `base.html.twig` `<head>` tag,this changes the css of the site.

**--What do I need to do?**

What I need to do to avoid conflict? or is there any method to render text without making it editable? Something like `CKEDITOR.render(tagId)`

**--Some images:**
[image]

[image]

**With Regards**

Wiktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: 
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_framed.html#content-styles-vs-page-styles
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss

If you are using classic CKEditor then its contents are held inside an iframe with a separate document. In order to style that internal document CKEditor attaches `contents.css` to it. Since internal styles in separate CSS files are not being saved together with HTML or merged into HTML it is important that you use same styles inside `contents.css` as you would like to see on your target page (where saved content will be used).

This is not CKEditor bug but simply a different approach you need to apply inside your application.

If you are creating content for different pages you can either create one large `contents.css` file or, in case of any styles conflicts multiple CSS files which you can load dynamically based on some logic (it will require writing some code to handle that) using [contentsCss](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss) setting. Please note that in case of dynamic CSS switching you do not want to use `contentsCss` inside `config.js` file but directly in instance configuration on HTML page where you can use server-side tags to "spit out" correct configuration for CKEditor instance e.g.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
    language : 'en',
    // other configuration settings
    // ...
    contentsCss : [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css' ]
}
```

You can use server-side tag which will return whole editor configuration or simply only this part `contentsCss : [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css' ]` or even correct file paths when HTML is being rendered.